# Allowing a promise.all-like function to return optionally null results with flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a function that is very similar to `Promise.all` except that it catches errors and returns `null` for any promise that throws:

```
export async function genNull<T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<?T> {
  try {
    return await promise;
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}

export function genAllNull<T: Array<Promise<mixed>>>(...promises: T): Promise<$TupleMap<T, typeof $await>> {
  return Promise.all(promises.map(genNull));
}
```

The problem that I'm trying to solve now is that I can't figure out how to annotate the `genAllNull` function properly so that the results are all nullable.  e.g. if I write:

```
const [foo, bar] = await genAllNull(Promise.resolve(42), Promise.resolve(43));
```

I want `foo` and `bar` to both have a flow type of `?Number`, but they have `Number` instead, i.e. flow doesn't see them as nullable.  I can't figure out how to annotate the function signatures so that the return types are nullable.

Comment: You can simplify your function to `return promise.then(null, () => null)`

Comment: @SLaks -- I'm assuming you're referring to the `genNull` function?  I still want to pass the promise value back if it exists ;)

Comment: Yes; not passing a success handler will do that.

Comment: @HMR -- that's exactly what Slacks said ;)  But that's not the actual issue I'm trying to fix

Comment: @HMR - Yes, that signature is correct if all the types were the same.  I tried things like `: Promise<$TupleMap<T, ?typeof $await>>`, but it doesn't like me passing nullable types to `$TupleMap` (which is conveniently undocumented, but it's what `Promise.all` uses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following errors properly with `null not compatible with number` properly:

```
export async function genNull<T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<T | null> {
  try {
    return await promise;
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}

export function genAllNull<Item, T: Array<Promise<Item>>>(
  ...promises: T
): Promise<$TupleMap<T, <V>(i: Promise<V>) => V | null>> {
  return Promise.all(promises.map(genNull));
}

async function fn(){
  const [foo, bar] = await genAllNull(Promise.resolve(43), Promise.resolve(43));

  var val1: number = foo;
  var val2: number = bar;
}
```

([On Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcwBDAZwE8A7AYzCgFdbCBLOKsAcwyoDkGYMADwAVAHwAKHPjgBbFmQwAuMAAUZ8xaLEBKFerkKMosAB8wVATDFgA3qjBhC+CnYeOw+DIQb4OJBBIWYmlDRQBudwBfMBoSQhoACzAJDHx8HTcPT29fDktBSMco1BLMXAJiRmY2Dm4qAEFBfkEhAElCDFkAGjARFQb0kgohA01jDq6xaYl3ADoF0PGyFRFUPTUNIyEAEhEGHBgMAFkSHFFeoQA1SRZ9La0bzIBeGyuzCytprJyfP02whg5iRBFIHhgyHNZGcJPUWjAdDpImVyNQ6NUaKx2PQqBIdPZHDR2GRiABtKBwOC9ABGJHwAF0wM9SIFglweE0YPCJGMjHMvGQ4DAAG4YCQAFgAzDperzFPyIULRRLpUj3O5hXSwJqYABGFSWWTUtJM+iUorarU6gBMBoYRpNzNp+GRQA))

First off, I ditched the use of `?T` in favor of `T | null` since `?T` is actually `T | null | undefined` and you said you only wanted `null` to be added.

Second, changed `mixed` to be an actual parameterized type, and third changed `typeof $await` to be `<V>(i: Promise<V>) => V | null` since that reflects the conversion that you're doing.

Comment: thanks so much!  Wasn't aware of `?T` encapsulating `undefined`, so that's a huge help in general too.  I also finally understand what was going on in the `Promise.all` definition.